# Jetbrains IDE'S putting the closing curly braces or parenthesis automatically

Tags: jetbrains-ide, parentheses, curly-braces

Sometimes, we put our bare "if" statements into the code without adding the curly braces if it is composed of only one expression. Unlike Sublime Code Completer, it is a hassle to put the enclosing parenthesis or curly braces around my statements in the Jetbrains Products. I mean

```
if (something)
   statement
```

when I pressed to "{", I want for ide to put the enclosing one at the end of the statement instead of putting adjacent to the newly put opening one.

Not like this:

```
if (something) {}
   statement
```

Intended form:

```
if (something){
   statement
}
```

Is there a way to configure as wanted?

Comment: I solved this by always using the curly braces. The benefits of _sometimes_ not using them are minimal, but the downsides are real.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I know, there is not a way to enclose a code block exactly the way you are looking for, but there is a similar feature available without too much more work. If you simply select the code you would like to wrap and enter an opening bracket, IntelliJ will wrap your code in the brackets and place both the brackets on their proper line given your coding style.